# Update bean property at runtime

Tags: java, spring, spring-ioc

I have a bean that holds some configuration:

```
public class CustomerService{
  private Config config;

  @Required
  public void setConfig(Config config){
    this.config = config;
  }
}

public Config {
  private String login;
  private String password;

  //setters/getters
}
```

app-context.xml:

```
<bean id="config" class="Config"/>
<bean id="customerService" class="CustomerService">
   <property name="config" ref="config"/>
</bean>
```

and the config values are obtained at runtime (by calling api).
How to update those values at runtime? Can I do it using a setter:

```
customerService.getConfig().setLogin("login");
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Inject your Spring context first in needed place

```
@Autowired
ApplicationContext context;
```

Obtain `customerService` instance from Spring context

```
CustomerService service = context.getBean(CustomerService.class);
```

Do needed changes on `service` in runtime

```
service.getConfig().setLogin("login");
```

UPDATE: you also can obtaine from the context just your `Config` instance

```
context.getBean(Config.class).setLogin("login");
```

Comment: what is the scope for Config bean? prototype?

Comment: I meant what should be a proper bean scope?